# Tips for searching and replacing file contents in entire filesystem

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream

I am in charge of developing an application for running on production servers and it aims to search and replace some specific string in every ini, xml and config file extensions and I must care about performance (total of 150 servers). Before replace I must backup the file. What the best way to accomplish this? As an aside, I can use Dot Net 4.0 but it is preferable to use 3.5 because no every server has 4.0 but if there is a serious advantage I can update to 4.0. Now I am thinking something like this:

```
String[] arrayFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strFylesystem , strExtensao, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string s in arrayFiles ){
            File.Copy(pathOrigin + s, pathNew);
            searchFound = false;
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(pathNew + s){
                if (line.contains("string_searched")){
                    line.Replace("string_searched", new_string);
                    searchFound = true;
                }
                if (!searchFound){
                    File.Delete(pathNew + s);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have found some forums using Lambda, PLINQ e Regular Expression. Beyond personal preferences, would some those help me about performance? For example: would be better performance if instead of using `File.ReadAllLines` I develop using `StreamReader`? Is there someway to wrap the `findStr` from windows and get performance improvement?

Comment: Really, every INI and XML files on every disk?

Comment: This sounds like a job for a Powershell script. One example can be found [here](http://poshcode.org/1707). Disclaimer: I haven't tried the script I linked. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: Are you having to run this script a lot? It almost sounds like something you'd need to run once and then be happy. If that's the case, why is performance an issue?

Comment: Alexn, yes, every INI and XML files and some more extensions?

Comment: PHeiberg, thanks for your suggestion. I will read it.

Comment: Anthony, yes, I will run only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your limiting factor will be disk access speed, and there's not much you can do to speed that up. Certainly, using Lambda expressions isn't going to make a performance difference.

Searching in parallel won't help unless you have multiple drives. That is, having two threads working on different directories on the same drive will probably slow things down because they'll be in contention for disk access.

One potential problem is that you're creating new files on the drive while you're enumerating all the files on the drive. If you're not careful you could get into an infinite loop. That is, you read x.xml, create a new file, x.new.xml, and then you find x.new.xml, change it, etc. You're probably better off scanning the entire drive and building a list of files that you want to change. Then go through that list, making the changes.

I would recommend that you not do this with C#. Instead, write two PowerShell scripts. The first one searches the drive for files that match your criteria, and writes those file names to a file. The second one reads file names from that file, and processes the files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065/56778 for an example.

That likely won't be quite as fast as a C# program, but I doubt it'd be a whole lot slower. Again, your limiting factor is disk access speed, not processing speed. And your development time will be a couple of hours rather than several days. And it'll be easier to modify the PowerShell script than it would be to modify a C# program.

Comment: Jim Mischel, thanks for your comments. Do you know how can I discovery  if a file is editable or not? I mean, imagine I don't have every extensions the previous developer has used to set up names of servers in the application. For instance, for some reason, a developer has hard code the name of server in a file called my_config.server which is basically an text file editable in notepad but the extension is different of .config or .ini. Is there a secure  way in C# to discover that this is a text file and not a bytecode?

Comment: @Demetrio: The only way is to open the file and inspect it. If the file contains only ASCII characters and newlines or tabs, then it's editable. That's the simplest case. The problem is somewhat more involved if the file is in an 8-bit encoding (Cyrillic, for example), Unicode, UTF-8, or some multi-byte character set.